# Oracle SQL Developer - Looping Through Row Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table below where I know the the Start and End Positions in the Position Column. The table is order by Start Time in DESC order.

| ID | PREV End Time | Start Time | End Time | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 10:00 | 1/1/2022 10:30 | 1/1/2022 11:30 | Start |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 12:30 | 1/1/2022 13:30 | 1/1/2022 14:30 | null |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 15:30 | 1/1/2022 16:30 | 1/1/2022 17:30 | End |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 18:30 | 1/1/2022 19:30 | 1/1/2022 20:30 | Start |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 21:30 | 1/1/2022 22:30 | 1/1/2022 23:30 | null |
| 1 | 1/2/2022 0:30 | 1/2/2022 1:30 | 1/2/2022 2:30 | null |
| 1 | 1/2/2022 3:30 | 1/2/2022 4:30 | 1/2/2022 5:30 | End |

I want to be able to make two new columns where I can identify Trip 1 and 2 distinctly. And I also want to number each leg for each trip. Below, is the table I desire.

| ID | PREV End Time | Start Time | End Time | Position | LEG | Trip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 10:00 | 1/1/2022 10:30 | 1/1/2022 11:30 | Start | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 12:30 | 1/1/2022 13:30 | 1/1/2022 14:30 | null | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 15:30 | 1/1/2022 16:30 | 1/1/2022 17:30 | End | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 18:30 | 1/1/2022 19:30 | 1/1/2022 20:30 | Start | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 21:30 | 1/1/2022 22:30 | 1/1/2022 23:30 | null | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1/2/2022 0:30 | 1/2/2022 1:30 | 1/2/2022 2:30 | null | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 1/2/2022 3:30 | 1/2/2022 4:30 | 1/2/2022 5:30 | End | 4 | 2 |

Sometimes the data, isn't as perfect as the first row starting as the Start position. Sometimes it starts in the middle of a trip. How can I exclude? And sometimes the end, ends in the middle of a trip. How can I exclude?

Please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: In the Preference --> Database --> NLS --> Date Format is MM-DD-RRRR HH24:MI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to do row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       PREV_End_Time,
       Start_Time,
       End_Time,
       Position,
       Leg,
       Trip
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY ID
  ORDER     BY start_time
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS trip,
    COUNT(*) AS leg
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (start_row intermediate_row* end_row)
  DEFINE
    start_row        AS position = 'Start',
    intermediate_row AS position IS NULL,
    end_row          AS position = 'End'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, PREV_End_Time, Start_Time, End_Time, Position) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '10:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '11:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '13:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '14:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '15:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '17:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'End'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '18:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '19:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '20:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '21:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '22:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '23:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-02' + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-02' + INTERVAL '01:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '02:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-02' + INTERVAL '03:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-02' + INTERVAL '04:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'End'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | PREV_END_TIME | START_TIME | END_TIME | POSITION | LEG | TRIP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 2022-01-01 10:30:00 | 2022-01-01 11:30:00 | Start | 1 | 1 |
> | 1 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | 2022-01-01 13:30:00 | 2022-01-01 14:30:00 | *null* | 2 | 1 |
> | 1 | 2022-01-01 15:30:00 | 2022-01-01 16:30:00 | 2022-01-01 17:30:00 | End | 3 | 1 |
> | 1 | 2022-01-01 18:30:00 | 2022-01-01 19:30:00 | 2022-01-01 20:30:00 | Start | 1 | 2 |
> | 1 | 2022-01-01 21:30:00 | 2022-01-01 22:30:00 | 2022-01-01 23:30:00 | *null* | 2 | 2 |
> | 1 | 2022-01-02 00:30:00 | 2022-01-02 01:30:00 | 2022-01-01 02:30:00 | *null* | 3 | 2 |
> | 1 | 2022-01-02 03:30:00 | 2022-01-02 04:30:00 | 2022-01-01 05:30:00 | End | 4 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f130a087350f2347ace23463089c72f5)*

Comment: Wow. I will need to understand what this is doing. But that worked. Thank you!